# How to Disable and Enable a button using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have three checkboxes 'a','b','c' and a button 'X'.
if initially 'a' and 'b' are checked and 'c' is unchecked, 'x' should be disabled.
otherwise for any combination other than the above, 'x' should be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-disabled.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

```
<button ng-disabled="$ctrl.checked">Button</button>
```

Update the **$ctrl.checked** to true/false in the controller as your logic needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ng-disabled for disable and show button

```
<button ng-disabled="$scope.a && $scope.b && $scope.c">Button</button>
```